# Are Stack communities fundamentally incompatible with Jewish learning?

Tags: chinuch-education

What would happen if שאינו יודע לשאול encountered a Stack site?  Is the practice of downvoting and the general ethos of having community-imposed standards for *questions* in conflict with tenets of Jewish education?   Or does the *Four Sons* lesson only apply to father and son, and very much not to the internet?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! This post reads as a statement rather than as a request for information, so I've closed it. If you have suggestions for improving the community or site, please take a look at [Meta]. I strongly recommend searching for and reading relevant previous material first, to see if your concerns have been discussed before.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122812/discussion-on-question-by-jay613-are-stack-communities-fundamentally-incompatibl).

Comment: @IsaacMoses  Two of the comments you deleted were answers, good ones, to the question that were placed in comments because you closed the question.  Anyway, I accept the idea that this is too meta for this forum.  Thank you.

Comment: @jay plenty of questions that should and will be closed here have real answers. For example, all the currently answered questions on Biology.SE would have been closed if asked here.

Comment: @jay613 I closed this post because it reads as a statement, meant to advance an argument, rather than a question, meant to solicit information, not because it's too meta. Questions about how Judaism applies to the special case of online Q&A forums are on-topic here. If you have such a question, you're welcome to edit this post to pose it. The comments I deleted are preserved in a dedicated chat room.

Comment: @IsaacMoses the Chat to which comments were moved, has vanished.  Is that to be expected, do Chats expire?

Comment: @jay613 Chat rooms get automatically "deleted" after some number of days of inactivity. Moderators can still see and undelete them.